# Why does G-d carry out all the curses by Himself?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, theology, curse, ki-tavo

In [Parashat Ki Tavo (28:15-on)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.28.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) Moses threatens the Nation with very descriptive curses. It starts from a distance:

> 'וּבָאוּ עָלֶיךָ כָּל־הַקְּלָלוֹת הָאֵלֶּה וְהִשִּׂיגוּךָ׃ אָרוּר אַתָּה וכו

One would understand that without G-d's closeness and providence all the bad things will happen all by themselves.

But very quickly it turns personal:

> יְשַׁלַּח ה' בְּךָ אֶת־הַמְּאֵרָה
>   יַדְבֵּק ה' בְּךָ אֶת־הַדָּבֶר
>   יַדְבֵּק ה' בְּךָ אֶת־הַדָּבֶר
>   יִתֵּן ה' אֶת־מְטַר אַרְצְךָ אָבָק
>   יַכְּכָה ה' בִּשְׁחִין, etc

G-d Himself will orchestrate and carry out all the curses "עַד הִשָּׁמְדָךְ" until He will exterminate us totally.

In the Story of Exodus, it is stressed that G-d Himself came down to Egypt and performed the Exodus, He and not [even] an angel.

Why in the curses it is important that G-d Himself will curry them out personally and that will not happen "naturally"?

Comment: Does one and the other have to mutually exclusive?

Comment: @Ilja what one and the other?